# How to return promise from recursive method

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I'm actually working with Firebase in a Javascript project, and trying to get informations of nested child of all elements of in a collections.

Since I need to recursively trigger the db, I'm trying to create a self calling recursive method that will map the actual db schema and pull needed data.

For the purpose of this post, I created fake method that demonstrate my actual logic. Maybe someone could help me, it's a never ending loop that trigger the last item infinitely. It never store the first results

```
function fakeWait(toReturn) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function(){ resolve(toReturn); }, 8000);
  });
}

function callMe(params = null) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log('Promise called', {...params});

    const promises = [];

    if (params === null) {
      promises.push(fakeWait(
        {
          id1:{title:'Title1'},
          id2:{title:'Title2'},
          id3:{title:'Title3'},
          id4:{title:'Title4'},
        }).then(results => {
          params = {};
          params.formations = results;
          resolve(callMe(params));
        }));
    }

    else {
      if (!params.hasOwnProperty('formationId') && 
          params.hasOwnProperty('formations')) {
        Object.keys(params.formations).forEach(formationId => {
          params.formationId = formationId;
          promises.push(resolve(callMe(params)));
        });
            }

      else if (params.hasOwnProperty('formationId') && 
               params.hasOwnProperty('formations') && 
               !params.formations[params.formationId].hasOwnProperty.modules) 
      {
        promises.push(fakeWait({
          id1:{title:'Title1.1'},
          id2:{title:'Title1.2'},
          id3:{title:'Title1.3'},
          id4:{title:'Title1.4'},
        }).then(result => {
          params.formations[params.formationId].modules = result;
          resolve(callMe(params));
        }))
            }
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => { console.log('Resolved.'); resolve(params); }).catch(()=> reject('oops'));
  });
}

callMe().then(results =>console.log(results)).catch(msg => console.log(msg));
```

You can also view and try the code on a stackblitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wuvp9z

Firebase data structure :

```
Formations - Collection
- Formation - Document
-- Modules - Collection
--- Module - Document
---- Chapters - Collection
----- Chapter - Document
------ Screens - Collection
------- Screen - Document
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172098/discussion-on-question-by-jonathan-lafleur-how-to-return-promise-from-recursive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code of a Firestore transaction that will write a new Screen document and update the `nbrScreens` counters in, respectively, the Formation, Module and Chapter parent documents.

It is a full HTML page. Do as follows:

1/ Adapt your Firebase config values in the HTML.

2/ Create, in Firestore, the parent collections and documents, with the desired Ids.

3/ For each document (Formation, Module and Chapter) add a field of type number named `nbrScreens` with value 0

4/ Adapt, in the HTML page, the value of `screenId`, `screenData` and the parameters of the `setNewScreen()` function call to what you want.

5/ Open the page in a browser (e.g. locally), the function will be called and the transaction executed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>

    var config = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "..."
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var firestoredb = firebase.firestore();


    function setNewScreen(formationId, moduleId, chapterId, screenId, screenData) {

        var formationDocRef = firestoredb.collection("Formations").doc(formationId);
        var moduleDocRef = formationDocRef.collection("Modules").doc(moduleId);
        var chapterDocRef = moduleDocRef.collection("Chapters").doc(chapterId);
        var screenDocRef = chapterDocRef.collection("Screens").doc(screenId);

        return firestoredb.runTransaction(function (transaction) {

            var newChaptersNbrScreens;
            var newModulesNbrScreens;
            var newFormationsNbrScreens;

            return transaction.get(chapterDocRef)
                .then(function (sfDoc) {

                    if (!sfDoc.exists) {
                        throw "Document Chapter does not exist!";
                    }

                    newChaptersNbrScreens = sfDoc.data().nbrScreens + 1;
                    return transaction.get(moduleDocRef);

                })
                .then(function (sfDoc) {

                    if (!sfDoc.exists) {
                        throw "Document Module does not exist!";
                    }

                    newModulesNbrScreens = sfDoc.data().nbrScreens + 1;
                    return transaction.get(formationDocRef);

                })
                .then(function (sfDoc) {

                    if (!sfDoc.exists) {
                        throw "Document Formation does not exist!";
                    }

                    newFormationsNbrScreens = sfDoc.data().nbrScreens + 1;
                    return transaction
                        .set(formationDocRef, {nbrScreens: newFormationsNbrScreens}, { merge: true })
                        .set(moduleDocRef, {nbrScreens: newModulesNbrScreens}, { merge: true })
                        .set(chapterDocRef, {nbrScreens: newChaptersNbrScreens}, { merge: true })
                        .set(screenDocRef, screenData)

                });

        });

    }


    //Calling the function
    //The formation, module and chapter docs must be created before calling it!!

    var screenId = 's1';
    var screenData = {title: 'screenTitle_s1', content: 'foo'};

    setNewScreen("f1", "m1", "c1", screenId, screenData)  //Screen will be saved under Formation f1, Module m1 and Chapter c1
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
        });


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can adapt the code in order to create the Formation, Module and Chapter. As a matter of fact this cannot be done in the transaction **because all read(s) shall be executed before the write(s)**.

You could something like (pseudo-code):

```
FormationDocumentReference.set({}) // <- returns a promise
.then(function() {
    ModuleDocumentReference.set({}) // <- returns a promise
})
.then(function() {
    ChapterDocumentReference.set({}) // <- returns a promise
})
.then(function() {
    setNewScreen(id_f, id_m1, id_c1, screenId, screenData)  // <- returns a promise
.then(function () {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

Finally, here is a couple of notable points about the transaction code above:

1/ `transaction.get()` returns a promise containing non-null `firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot`, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get). Therefore you have to chain them with `then()`.

2/ On the other hand, `transaction.set()` returns "This Transaction instance", see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set). Therefore you should just chain them one after the other (like `return transaction.set().set()...`)

Comment: Big thanks for your time and explanation! I really appreciate it!